# Python flow how to manage it in classes

Tags: python

I'm just curious how to handle better in OOP.

Assume when I create class something like this:

```
class MakeMeMeow:
    def __init__(self, who):
        self.who = who
    
    def return_who_meow(self):
        return self.who
```

I have something to do like this:

```
cat = MakeMeMeow("SuperMeow")
cat.return_who_meow()
```

I know I can do something like:

```
def __init__(self, who):
    self.who = who

    self.return_who_meow(self)
```

But in my opinion it's not so elegant, how can I make it more pythonic? `repr` function is not what I'm looking for - I want many more logic in function like this.

Comment: Your "I know I can do something like" makes no sense since (a) you're not returning the value from `return_who_meow()` and (b) `__init__()` can't return anything anyway.

Comment: When you have two methods, one of which is `__init__`, you should [stop writing classes](https://youtu.be/o9pEzgHorH0). That should maybe be a function or, given you don't actually change the input at all, _nothing_.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve! What is wrong with code snippets 1 and 2?

Comment: I want to wrap it and return value as class definition dont want to create instance and call functions 10 times.... Just want to hide all the logic inside and dunno how to achieve the best flow to do it.... Need help with how to good manage state inside a class